# Get json response from "create" function in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, format, ruby-on-rails-5

```
  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

i just want to know how to make "def create" return me the show.json.builder after save the post

This is my form where i send the info to "def create", i already try to add the attribute :"data-type" => "json", but it doesn't work, and call by the method POST with the action "/posts.json" it doesn't call the function "create" just show all the information that contain the object post when i send it

```
 <%= form_for post do |f| %>


     <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :body %>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>


 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this

```
 <%= form_for(@post, format: :json) do |f| %>

    ----
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Also you should consider adding remote: true if you want this to be handled with ajax.

Comment: Thaaanks you save me!!! i try earlier with html: {:format => 'json'} and didn't work, you why?

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps they you were reading documentation/tutorials on an older rails version which aren't true anymore